# Is $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ (Tychonoff product topology of Euclidean $\mathbb{R}$) a Menger or a Hurewicz space?

Tags: general-topology

A topological space $X$ is said to be a

1. Menger space if for each sequence $(\mathcal{U}_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there is a sequence $(\mathcal{V}_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal{V}_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal{U}_n$ and $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{V}_n$ is an open cover of $X$.
2. Hurewicz space if for each sequence $(\mathcal{U}_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there is a sequence $(\mathcal{V}_n)$ such that for each $n$ $\mathcal{V}_n$ is a finite subset of $\mathcal{U}_n$ and each $x\in X$ belongs to $\cup\mathcal{V}_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.
3. Rothberger space if for each sequence $(\mathcal{U}_n)$ of open covers of $X$ there is a sequence $(U_n)$ such that for each $n$ $U_n\in\mathcal{U}_n$ and $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}U_n=X$.

I know that $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is not $\sigma$-compact and as well as not Rothberger. But I don't know whether $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is Megner or Hurewicz.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: For $n\in\Bbb N$ and $k\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$U_n(k)=\{\langle x_i:i\in\Bbb N\rangle\in\Bbb R^\omega:|x_n|<k\}\,,$$

and for $n\in\Bbb N$ let $\mathscr{U}_n=\{U_n(k):k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$. Show that no matter how we choose finite subsets $\mathscr{V}_n\subseteq\mathscr{U}_n$, their union cannot cover $\Bbb R^\omega$, so $\Bbb R^\omega$ is not a Menger space. This also settles the question of whether $\Bbb R^\omega$ is a Hurewicz space.

Comment: I do not understand as if we consider any two members from two distinct $\mathcal{U}_n$, then these members cover $\mathbb{R}^\omega$. Suppose that $U_1(1)\in\mathcal{U}_1$ and $U_2(1)\in\mathcal{U}_2$. Obviously $U_1(1)\cup U_2(1)=\mathbb{R}^\omega$.

Comment: @NurAlam: $U_1(1)\cup U_2(1)\ne\Bbb R^\omega$; for instance, it does not contain $\langle 2,2,2,\ldots\rangle$.